# EntityFramework and FluentAPI working with ComplexTypes

Tags: entity-framework, fluent, complextype

I am creating a new database model using Entity Framework 4.3 Code-FIrst; using Fluent API. Dummy model is below.

So my main object is Something and I need to keep track of this. All the other items are supplimentary. Normally in a Database I would assign a Table such as Contact, a primary key and a foregin key for relationship. However, reading more about about the Fluent API and [Complex Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295847%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), especially [this article](http://2guysfrommumbai.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/entity-framework-complex-types/), I have noticed (i think) that I can let EF take care of linking those objects/tables and I don't have to worry about them as Repositories in my MVC app.

So please note:

- Something has a one to many with Contact
- Contact has one to many with Address
- Contact has one to many with PhoenNumber

**Knowing this, my confusion lies in the Complex Types because Contact is a Complext Type to Somethign and Address & PhoneNumber are Complex Types to Something.**

- How would I set this relationship in Fluent API?
- How would I say that Address is required?
- Using domain driven development in ASP.NET MVC, would I have to maintain a repository of IContactRepository and IAddressRepository to push to a controller?

(please note that some code omitted for brevity.)

```
// attempt
void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Contact>();

    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Contact>().Property(p => p.Address).IsRequired();  // COMPILER ERROR

    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>();
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<PhoneNumber>();    
}


// DUMMY MODEL
class Something()
{
    void Something()
    {
        this.Contact = new HashSet<Contact>( );
    }

    DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    int YearsEmployed { get; set; }
    ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}

class Contact()
{
    void Contact()
    {
        this.Address = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

class Address()
{
        string Street1 { get; set; }
        string Street2 { get; set; }
        string State { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string Zip { get; set; }
        OptionName OptionName { get; set; }
}

class PhoneNumber()
{
    string Number
    OptionName OptionName { get; set; }
}

class OptionName()
{
    string OptionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that calling `modelBuilder.ComplexType<Contact>();` is the fluent way of applying `[ComplexType]` attribute to a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No neither of your classes is complex type. [Complex types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) must follow strict rules. They cannot contain navigation properties and because they are mapped to the owning entity's table they cannot be represented in any other form than one-to-one relation with owning entity.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So basically something like Address, PhoneNumber and Contact should be its own Entity with its own Id (i.e., PhoneNumberId, AddressId, etc)?